Unable to print logs in SpringBoot 3.3.0
2024-06-15 20:03:04 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet [http-nio-8080-exec-2] - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
The above is the log, when I tried to log a request body. I tried a few configs like
spring:
  codec:
    log-request-details: true

and then
debug:
  logging.http-requests: true
  
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        web: 
          server:
            adapter:
              HttpWebHandlerAdapter: TRACE

All I am trying to do is the below
@PostMapping("/bulkSetCollectionStatus")
public ResponseEntity<String> bulkSetCollectionStatus(@RequestBody BulkSetCollectionStatusDTO bulkSetCollectionStatusDTO) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Received BulkSetCollectionStatusDTO: " + bulkSetCollectionStatusDTO);

        logger.info("Received BulkSetCollectionStatusDTO: {}", bulkSetCollectionStatusDTO);


        return new ResponseEntity<>("BulkSetCollectionStatusDTO received successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Error processing bulkSetCollectionStatusDTO", e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Error processing request", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}

How do i set the below to true.
enableLoggingRequestDetails='false'

I am very new to SpringBoot 3.3.0 and am trying to explore. Please advice on what I am doing wrong or if I have to add any configs at my yml file. I can provide any necessary information you'd like on this. Also my first question in this platform. Thank you!
I wanted to print the request body to my log, to see how it looks an continue further from there.

Have you tried using spring.mvc.log-request-details=true?
